# How do I work with arrays of objects in PHP and how to get distinct product category and subcategory?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of Product objects, defined like so:

```
class Product{

    public $description;
    public $pricing;
    public $name;
    public $imageUrl;
    public $id;
    public $category;
    public $subcategory;

    public function __construct($id, $description, $pricing, $name, $imageUrl, ProductCategory $category, ProductSubCategory $subcategory){
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->pricing = $pricing;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->imageUrl = $imageUrl;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->subcategory = $subcategory;
    }

}
```

Each Product object has a category and subcategory object as part of the definition, these are defined as so:

ProductCategory:

```
class ProductCategory{
    public $name;
    public $id;

    public function __construct($categoryName, $categoryId){
        $this->name = $categoryName;
        $this->id = $categoryId;
    }
}
```

ProductSubCategory:

```
class ProductSubCategory{
    public $name;
    public $id;

    public function __construct($subCategoryName, $subCategoryId){
        $this->name = $subCategoryName;
        $this->id = $subCategoryId;
    }
}
```

For example, the parent category Non-Medicated has the following subcategories (parent category, subcategory):

```
Non Medicated, Glass
Non Medicated, Accesories
Non Medicated, Lip Balm
Non Medicated, Lotion
Non Medicated, Distillate
Non Medicated, Cartridges
Non Medicated, Tincture
Non Medicated, Capsules
```

I am trying to return an array of objects that is the main category as well as the distinct subcategories for each main category by iterating through the products, so that I can ultimately get a display like this:

- Non-Medicated

  - Glass
  - Accessories
  - Lip Balm
  - Lotion
  - Distillate
  - Cartridges
  - Tincture
  - Capsules

**What I've done so far:**

So far I can get the categories by doing this:

```
$categories  = array();
$allProducts = $this->get_all_products();

foreach ( $allProducts as $item ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $item->category, $categories ) ) {
        array_push( $categories, $item->category );
    }
}
print_r( $categories );
```

Where $allProducts is an array of Product objects, as defined above.

So I have this array:

```
Array ( [0] => ProductCategory Object ( [name] => Non Medicated [id] => 6 ) [1] => ProductCategory Object ( [name] => Infused Edible [id] => 4 ) [2] => ProductCategory Object ( [name] => Concentrate [id] => 2 ) [3] => ProductCategory Object ( [name] => Cartridges / Pens [id] => 3 ) [4] => ProductCategory Object ( [name] => Flower [id] => 1 ) )
```

What I am trying to do is get something here $categories[0][0] is the main category and then $categories[0][1] is subcategory 1, $categories[0][2] is subcategory 2, etc.

I am also open to approaching it another way - that's just the easiest I could think of off the top of my head. Any advice on how to better structure this would be appreciated as well. I have heard of Collections before, but I've never used them, and I'm not sure if they would be applicable here.

Comment: somehow I am feeling the application of groupBy. But unable to understand your question.

Comment: Hmm - I will look into array grouping.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question looks more ProductSubCategory belongs to ProductCategory object instead Product object.

Basically, I believe you can better design it by `Product` having a `ProductCategory` object and a `ProductCategory` having an array of `ProductSubCategory`. So, when you get the `Product` object, you have access to it `ProductCategory` and all `ProductSubCategory` objects.

So, you can iterate your objects like this:

```
foreach($allProducts as $product) {
    $category = $product->getCategory(); // Get your object category
    $subCategories = $category->getSubCategories(); // Get your sub categories from CategoryObject
    echo "Category: " . $category;
    foreach($subCategories as $subCategory) {
        echo "Sub category: " . $subCategory;
    }
}
```

You can get the result you were expecting in your question above.

Comment: Also, don't use your class fields as public: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is a function to get all sub categories for a given category

```
$categories  = array();
$allProducts = $this->get_all_products();
foreach ( $allProducts as $key => $item ) {
    $categories[$key][] = $item->category;
    foreach ($this->get_all_subcategories($item->category) as $subCat) { //assuming there is a get_all_subcategories function available, it could be an array with category as the key and subcategories as the value
        $categories[$key][] = $subCat;
    }
}

print_r( $categories );
```

Modification

```
$categories  = array();
$allProducts = $this->get_all_products();
foreach ( $allProducts as $key => $item ) {
    $categories[$key][0] = $item->category;
    if (!in_array($item->subcategory, $categories[$key]))
        $categories[$key][] = $item->subcategory;
}

print_r( $categories );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no function, that's the functionality I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added another version assuming subcategory can be fetched by $item->subcategory

Comment: Your update was very helpful! I am now getting an array back containing 187 (all products) elements, I just need to figure out how to de-dupe the array so that I am left with a unique set of categories and subcategories.

Comment: Shouldnt if (!in_array($item->subcategory, $categories[$key])) take care of it! Or a subcategory can be inside two diff categories?

Comment: I think the problem is that it is iterating through the entire $allProducts array (contains 187 items) and declaring a new category for each item when in fact that category may already exist in the array. I think I need to loop through the 4 main categories, then append the relevant subcategories from the individual items, rather than loop through each item?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it in one loop:

```
$allCategories = [];
foreach($allProducts as $product){
    if(!isset($allCategories[$product->category)) // add the category
        $allCategories[$product->category] = [];   
    if(!isset($allCategories[$product->category][$product->subcategory])) // add the subcategory to top-level category
        $allCategories[$product->category][] = $product->subcategory;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it appears to be stuck in an infinite loop?